# Dynamic data type in Workflow Foundation 4

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Can I use dynamic data type in WF 4.0? And if this is possible then how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are creating activities or workflow extensions in code you can use dynamic data types just like in any other place in C#. When using VB expressions inside of a XAML workflow you can't. Even though VB has plenty of dynamic capabilities by setting option strict off there is no way to do that in a workflow and all expressions are compiled using set strict on and set explicit on.